# Incrementing Integer Without Parsing Array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php form that submits to MySQL, and a 2nd php form that uses the value stored via the first.

The highest value in the database for booth_member is currently 3. In the example below, = $booth_member should be equal to 4, but instead always returns 2.

```
$membersql = $mysqli->query("SELECT booth_member FROM users WHERE booth_number = '{$user['booth_number']}' ORDER BY booth_member DESC LIMIT 1");
$booth_member = $membersql + 1;
echo $booth_member;
```

If I try and echo $membersql, it simply returns 'array.'

Comment: Please check `mysqli` documentation on how to retrieve the data from query.

Comment: @zerkms Link? Source? Fix? Anything useful?

Comment: You need to `fetch()` the result(s) before you can use them.  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: @WolfInd: I omitted it intentionally. One must learn how to work with documentation. It actually must be the first step before you learn anything new.

Comment: @zerkms He's obviously just getting started with php. Point him in the right direction (which is php.net here) so that he get's to know the first ressource in this case (alltough w3schools may be an alternative).

Comment: @Sebb they're doing php for at least 2.5 months :-S

Comment: @zerkms Didn't look like that to be honest. In that case, I totally agree with you. However I'll keep the link for a poor guy who's really just getting started :p

Comment: @WolfInd No problem. But when using php you should always have a look at the php docs at [php.net](http://php.net/docs.php) and then search for it on google, that saves a lot of time and maybe helps you to not get mad with php ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli::query` returns a ressource object, that's why it's not working. Some code to fix it:

```
$membersql = $mysqli->query("SELECT booth_member FROM users WHERE booth_number = '{$user['booth_number']}' ORDER BY booth_member DESC LIMIT 1");
if($membersql->num_rows < 1)
{ /* error handling goes here */ }
else
{
  $res_array = $membersql->fetch_assoc(); // save result as array
  $booth_member = $res_array["booth_member"] + 1;
  echo $booth_member;
}
```

Be sure to escape `$user['booth_number']` before to prevent sql injection.

For more info, check the [mysqli::query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) documentation :)

Answer (score 0):

You require a bunch of try/catch code around this for a production system, but to test:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT booth_member FROM users WHERE booth_number = '{$user['booth_number']}' ORDER BY booth_member DESC LIMIT 1");

$booth_member = $result->fetch_object('booth_member');
++$booth_member;
echo $booth_member;
```

Answer (score -2):

That's because it's an array. I believe you are trying to do:

```
$booth_member = $membersql['booth_member'] + 1;
```

Comment: Can you just do `$membersql['booth_member']` without first calling `fetch()`?  Pretty sure you can't do that.